# segmentation arabic word character by character python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to segment handwritten Arabic words into characters from picture.. Which algorithm may I follow to achieve this? How can I do that using python or matLab? Or can I use the histogram approach? Also, How can I implement this in python or matlab ?please I need help and an easy and clear approach so I can follow it.

[image]

i want to segment the image to get this result (each character in a picture)

[image] 
 [image]   [image]

[image]

this is a code i found it in github ,it's for english cursive handwrting :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import traceback

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
fn=0
path='result/'

#Taking any image from the sample images
#In case of slanted image, straighten it using image-straighten.py, then use it
img = cv.imread('sample_images/7.PNG')

# In[findFeaturPoints]
def findCapPoints(img):
    cpoints=[]
    dpoints=[]
    for i in range(img.shape[1]):
        col = img[:,i:i+1]
        k = col.shape[0]
        while k > 0:
            if col[k-1]==255:
                dpoints.append((i,k))
                break
            k-=1

        for j in range(col.shape[0]):
            if col[j]==255:
                cpoints.append((i,j))
                break
    return cpoints,dpoints


# In[wordSegment]
#*****************************************************************************#
def wordSegment(textLines):
    wordImgList=[]
    counter=0
    cl=0
    for txtLine in textLines:
        gray = cv.cvtColor(txtLine, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        th, threshed = cv.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        final_thr = cv.dilate(threshed,None,iterations = 20)

        plt.imshow(final_thr)
        plt.show()

        contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(final_thr,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        boundingBoxes = [cv.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
        (contours, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, boundingBoxes), key=lambda b: b[1][0], reverse=False))

        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv.contourArea(cnt)

#            print area
            if area > 10000:
                print ('Area= ',area)
                x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
                print (x,y,w,h)
                letterBgr = txtLine[0:txtLine.shape[1],x:x+w]
                wordImgList.append(letterBgr)

                cv.imwrite("result/words/" + str(counter) +".jpg",letterBgr)
                counter=counter+1
        cl=cl+1

    return wordImgList
#*****************************************************************************#

# In[fitToSize]
#*****************************************************************************#
def fitToSize(thresh1):

    mask = thresh1 > 0
    coords = np.argwhere(mask)

    x0, y0 = coords.min(axis=0)
    x1, y1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1   # slices are exclusive at the top
    cropped = thresh1[x0:x1,y0:y1]
    return cropped

#*****************************************************************************#

# In[lineSegment]
#*****************************************************************************#
def lineSegment(img):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, threshed = cv.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv.THRESH_OTSU)

    upper=[]
    lower=[]
    flag=True
    for i in range(threshed.shape[0]):

        col = threshed[i:i+1,:]
        cnt=0
        if flag:
            cnt=np.count_nonzero(col == 255)
            if cnt >0:
                upper.append(i)
                flag=False
        else:
            cnt=np.count_nonzero(col == 255)
            if cnt <2:
                lower.append(i)
                flag=True
    textLines=[]
    if len(upper)!= len(lower):lower.append(threshed.shape[0])
#    print upper
#    print lower
    for i in range(len(upper)):
        timg=img[upper[i]:lower[i],0:]

        if timg.shape[0]>5:
#            plt.imshow(timg)
#            plt.show()
            timg=cv.resize(timg,((timg.shape[1]*5,timg.shape[0]*8)))
            textLines.append(timg)

    return textLines
#*****************************************************************************#

# In[baselines]:
##******************************************************************************#
def baselines(letter2, upoints, dpoints):
##-------------------------Creating upper baseline-------------------------------##
    colu = []
    for i in range(len(upoints)):
        colu.append(upoints[i][1])

    maxyu = max(colu)
    minyu = min(colu)
    avgu = (maxyu + minyu) // 2
    meanu = np.around(np.mean(colu)).astype(int)
    print('Upper:: Max, min, avg, mean:: ',maxyu, minyu, avgu, meanu)

##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------##
##-------------------------Creating lower baseline process 1--------------------------##
    cold = []
    for i in range(len(dpoints)):
        cold.append(dpoints[i][1])

    maxyd = max(cold)
    minyd = min(cold)
    avgd = (maxyd + minyd) // 2
    meand = np.around(np.mean(cold)).astype(int)
    print('Lower:: Max, min, avg, mean:: ',maxyd, minyd, avgd, meand)

##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------##
##-------------------------Creating lower baseline process 2---------------------------##
    cn = []
    count = 0

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if(letterGray[i,j] == 255):
                count+=1
        if(count != 0):
            cn.append(count)
            count = 0    
    maxindex = cn.index(max(cn))
    print('Max pixels at: ',maxindex)

##------------------Printing upper and lower baselines-----------------------------##

    cv.line(letter2,(0,meanu),(w,meanu),(255,0,0),2)
    lb = 0
    if(maxindex > meand):
        lb = maxindex
        cv.line(letter2,(0,maxindex),(w,maxindex),(255,0,0),2)
    else:
        lb = meand
        cv.line(letter2,(0,meand),(w,meand),(255,0,0),2)

    plt.imshow(letter2)
    plt.show()
    return meanu, lb
##******************************************************************************###

# In[histogram]:
##*******************************************************************************###
def histogram(letter2, upper_baseline, lower_baseline):
    ##------------Making Histograms (Default)------------------------######
    cropped = letter2[upper_baseline:lower_baseline,0:w]
    plt.imshow(cropped)
    plt.show()
    colcnt = np.sum(cropped==255, axis=0)
    x = list(range(len(colcnt)))
    plt.plot(colcnt)
    plt.fill_between(x, colcnt, 1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()  
    return colcnt     
####---------------------------------------------------------------------------#####

# In[Visualize]:
##*******************************************************************************###
def visualize(letter2, upper_baseline, lower_baseline, min_pixel_threshold, min_separation_threshold, min_round_letter_threshold):
    seg = []
    seg1 = []
    seg2 = []
   ## Check if pixel count is less than min_pixel_threshold, add segmentation point
    for i in range(len(colcnt)):
      if(colcnt[i] < min_pixel_threshold):
          seg1.append(i)

    ## Check if 2 consequtive seg points are greater than min_separation_threshold in distance
    for i in range(len(seg1)-1):
        if(seg1[i+1]-seg1[i] > min_separation_threshold):
            seg2.append(seg1[i])

##------------Modified segmentation for removing circles----------------------------###            
    arr=[]
    for i in (seg2):
        arr1 = []
        j = upper_baseline
        while(j <= lower_baseline):
            if(letterGray[j,i] == 255):
                arr1.append(1)
            else:
                arr1.append(0)
            j+=1
        arr.append(arr1)
    print('At arr Seg here: ', seg2)

    ones = []
    for i in (arr):
        ones1 = []
        for j in range(len(i)):
            if (i[j] == 1):
                ones1.append([j])
        ones.append(ones1)

    diffarr = []
    for i in (ones):
        diff = i[len(i)-1][0] - i[0][0]
        diffarr.append(diff)
    print('Difference array: ',diffarr)

    for i in range(len(seg2)):
        if(diffarr[i] < min_round_letter_threshold):
            seg.append(seg2[i])
##---------------------------------------------------------------------------##
    ## Make the Cut 
    for i in range(len(seg)):
        letter3 = cv.line(letter2,(seg[i],0),(seg[i],h),(255,0,0),2)

    print("Does it work::::")
    plt.imshow(letter3)
    plt.show()
    return seg 
###---------------------------------------------------------------------------#####  

# In[segmentCharacters]
def segmentCharacters(seg,lettergray):
    s=0
    wordImgList = []
    global fn
    for i in range(len(seg)):
        if i==0:
            s=seg[i]
            if s > 15:
                wordImg = lettergray[0:,0:s]
                cntx=np.count_nonzero(wordImg == 255) 
                print ('count',cntx)
                plt.imshow(wordImg)
                plt.show()
                fn=fn+1
            else:
                continue
        elif (i != (len(seg)-1)):
            if seg[i]-s > 15:
                wordImg = lettergray[0:,s:seg[i]]
                cntx=np.count_nonzero(wordImg == 255) 
                print ('count',cntx)
                plt.imshow(wordImg)
                plt.show()
                fn=fn+1
                s=seg[i]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            wordImg = lettergray[0:,seg[len(seg)-1]:]
            cntx=np.count_nonzero(wordImg == 255) 
            print ('count',cntx)
            plt.imshow(wordImg)
            plt.show()
            fn=fn+1
        wordImgList.append(wordImg)

    return wordImgList

#*****************************************************************************#
# In[Main]:
try:
    textLines=lineSegment(img)
    print ('No. of Lines',len(textLines))
    imgList=wordSegment(textLines)
    print ('No. of Words',len(imgList))
    counter = 0
    for letterGray in imgList:
        print ('LetterGray shape: ',letterGray.shape)
        gray = cv.cvtColor(letterGray, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        th, letterGray = cv.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        letterGray = fitToSize(letterGray)
        letter2 = letterGray.copy()
        letterGray = cv.dilate(letterGray,None,iterations = 4)

        h = letterGray.shape[0]
        w = letterGray.shape[1]

        upoints, dpoints=findCapPoints(letterGray)        
        meanu, lb = baselines(letter2, upoints, dpoints)

##-----------Final Baseline row numbers-----------------------####
#       Ignore all points avove and below these rows 
        upper_baseline = meanu
        lower_baseline = lb

##--------------------Make histogram-------------------------------------###   

        colcnt = histogram(letter2, upper_baseline, lower_baseline)

###------------------------Visualize segmentation------------------------------#####        
        ## Tuning Parameters
        min_pixel_threshold = 80
        min_separation_threshold = 60
        min_round_letter_threshold = 500

        seg = visualize(letter2, upper_baseline, lower_baseline, min_pixel_threshold, min_separation_threshold, min_round_letter_threshold)
        wordImgList = segmentCharacters(seg,letterGray)
        for i in wordImgList:
            cv.imwrite("result/characters/" + str(counter) +".jpeg",i)
            counter=counter+1

###---------------------------------------------------------------------------#####        

    print('Original Image')         
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

except Exception as e:
    print ('Error Message ',e)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
    traceback.print_exc()
    pass

traceback.print_exc()
```

the issue is i couldn't find the optimal parametr to segment the arabic word : this is the histograme that i get and i want to crop exactly  in evry end of the curves :
[image]

thankx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ok the english cursive one is a great example, but you would have to train it on images of Arabic writing.

One good idea: download an image dataset of Arabic characters.  This one would be great: https://www.kaggle.com/mloey1/ahcd1

Then, train an object detection machine to use it.  It should be able to point out, in an image of an Arabic word or sentence, which characters are being used.  You could then use the dimensions of the bounding box for each character, and output an image for each one, cropped to just that character.

Comment: hey friend , thnx for ur answer , i all ready create and train my model for arabic character and digit recognition , can u interduce me please how can i create an object detector